# Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT. Airflow task fails with SnowflakeOperator

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler, snowflake-schema

Running this DAG in airflow gives error as Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT.

I am not sure what is wrong I have done

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
    from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
    
    SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID = 'snowflake_conn'
    # TODO: should be able to rely on connection's schema, but currently param required by S3ToSnowflakeTransfer
    # SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'
    #SNOWFLAKE_STAGE = 'stage_name'
    SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE = 'SF_TUTS_WH'
    SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE = 'KAFKA_DB'
    SNOWFLAKE_ROLE = 'sysadmin'
    SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_TABLE = 'sample_table'
    
    CREATE_TABLE_SQL_STRING = (
        f"CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE {SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_TABLE} (name VARCHAR(250), id INT);"
    )
    
    SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT = f"INSERT INTO {SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_TABLE} VALUES ('name', %(id)s)"
    SQL_LIST = [SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT % {"id": n} for n in range(0, 10)]
    
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
    }
    
    dag = DAG(
        'example_snowflake',
        default_args=default_args,
        start_date=days_ago(2),
        tags=['example'],
    )
    
    snowflake_op_sql_str = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='snowflake_op_sql_str',
        dag=dag,
        snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
        sql=CREATE_TABLE_SQL_STRING,
        warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
        database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
      #  schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
        role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
    )
    
    snowflake_op_with_params = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='snowflake_op_with_params',
        dag=dag,
        snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
        sql=SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT,
        parameters={"id": 56},
        warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
        database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
     #   schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
        role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
    )
    
    
    snowflake_op_sql_list = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='snowflake_op_sql_list', dag=dag, snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID, sql=SQL_LIST
    )
    
    snowflake_op_sql_str >> [
        snowflake_op_with_params,
        snowflake_op_sql_list,]
```

**Getting LOGS in airFlow as below ::**

```
 Reading local file: /Users/aashayjain/airflow/logs/snowflake_test/snowflake_op_with_params/2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00/1.log
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,880] {taskinstance.py:826} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: snowflake_test.snowflake_op_with_params 2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,887] {taskinstance.py:826} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: snowflake_test.snowflake_op_with_params 2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,887] {taskinstance.py:1017} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,887] {taskinstance.py:1018} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,887] {taskinstance.py:1019} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,892] {taskinstance.py:1038} INFO - Executing <Task(SnowflakeOperator): snowflake_op_with_params> on 2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,895] {standard_task_runner.py:51} INFO - Started process 16510 to run task
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,901] {standard_task_runner.py:75} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'snowflake_test', 'snowflake_op_with_params', '2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00', '--job-id', '7', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/snowflake_test.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/6h/1pzt4pbx6h32h6p5v503wws00000gp/T/tmp1w61m38s']
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,903] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Job 7: Subtask snowflake_op_with_params
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,933] {logging_mixin.py:103} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: snowflake_test.snowflake_op_with_params 2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00 [running]> on host 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,954] {taskinstance.py:1232} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=snowflake_test
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=snowflake_op_with_params
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-02-02T13:51:18.229233+00:00
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,955] {snowflake.py:119} INFO - Executing: INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('name', %(id)s)
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,961] {base.py:74} INFO - Using connection to: id: snowflake_conn. Host: uva00063.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com, Port: None, Schema: , Login: aashay, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,963] {connection.py:218} INFO - Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.3.7, Python Version: 3.7.3, Platform: Darwin-19.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,964] {connection.py:769} INFO - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,964] {connection.py:785} INFO - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,996] {local_task_job.py:118} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
```

apache-airflow==2.0.0

python 3.7.3

Looking forward for help with this. let me know I need to provide any more details wrt. code or airflow...................................???

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error on Mac OSX - which looks like the OS you are using based on the local file path.

Adding the following to my Airflow *scheduler* session fixed the problem:

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

The cause is described in the [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-1.10.10/#running-airflow-on-macos):

> This error occurs because of added security to restrict
> multiprocessing & multithreading in Mac OS High Sierra and above.

The doc refers to version 1.10.x - but based on local test environments this also resolves the error for v2.x.x.

**kaxil** comment in the following issue actually guided me to the relevant Airflow page:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12808#issuecomment-738854764

Comment: For me I needed to add it to the webserver session as well.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me too on Mac OSX:

1. Open terminal an open .zshrc (or .bash_profile) with `nano .zshrc`
2. Add this line to the profile  `export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`
3. Restart scheduler & web server.

Comment: I spent more than 10 hours and nothing help and finally this appeared. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing:

```
snowflake_op_with_params = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='snowflake_op_with_params',
    dag=dag,
    snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
    sql=SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT,
    parameters={"id": 56},
    warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
    database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
 #   schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
    role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
)
```

This try to run the `sql` in `SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT`.
So it executes:

```
f"INSERT INTO {SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_TABLE} VALUES ('name', %(id)s)"
```

which gives:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES ('name', %(id)s)
```

As shown in your own log:

```
[2021-02-02 19:21:38,955] {snowflake.py:119} INFO - Executing: INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('name', %(id)s)
```

This is not a valid SQL statement.

I can't really tell what SQL you wanted to execute. Based on `SQL_LIST` I can assume that `%(id)s` suppose to be and id of integer type.

Comment: I hardcoded the sql statement
 INFO - Executing: INSERT INTO KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE VALUES('name', 123)
  INFO -Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.3.7, Python Version: 3.7.3, Platform: Darwin-19.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
  INFO - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
  INFO - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
  INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT

Comment: Still getting the same error. after hardcoding the SQL sql statement. This SQL is correct. tested in snowflake -->  INSERT INTO KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE VALUES('name', 123)

Comment: @Aashu Could the host defined in the connection be wrong? You are using ocsp. docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/… I believe your host should be: ocsp.*.snowflakecomputing.com:80

Comment: I also guess this will the issue. I have tried using what you suggested. As per the docs I tried  -- ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com:80     as well still getting same error. Thanks for looking into this. really appreciate your help.Please let me know your thoughts if something click to you to resolve this..

Comment: @Aashu `ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com:80` can't be the answer because it doesn't specify to what account you are trying to connect. I see you already opened a support request in snowflake python connector github. You might want to open an actual support case to snowflake. I wouldn't mention Airflow to them this will just confuse them. You are just trying to run a query with thier python wrapper. Airflow isn't the issue here. You might also want to read https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/245 not the same issue as yours but could be relvant

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing has to do with OCSP checking

Add "insecure_mode=True" in snowflake connector to disable OCSP checking

```py
snowflake.connector.connect(
   insecure_mode=True,
)
```

But "insecure_mode=True" is needed only when running inside Airflow (Running as a pyscript works fine) . I don't know why is that.

Note: export `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` didn't work for me because i didn't get this error
`may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.` which will usually throw `Negsignal.SIGABRT` exception

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ends up here when Googling SIGBART or SIGSEGV error in airflow. You might find it useful, at least i would, before i wasted some time trying to find the source of the problem.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/22273#discussioncomment-5379147